# Jquery refresh div but hold action on mouseover

Tags: jquery, append, refresh, mouseover

Good day all,

Ive been trying to get the following to work:
......including jquery.js from www..... this script is located in the header

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#latestChats").bind("mouseout", function() {
        refreshInterval = setInterval(function() {
            $("#latestChats").load('chatmessages.php');
        }, 1500);
    });

    $("#latestChats").bind("mouseover", function() {
        clearInterval(refreshInterval);
    });
</script>
```

I want to constantly refresh a div that contains chat messages from users and whenever a user clicks on a youtube vid/views content (mouseover) in this div that the refresh stops. A auto append jquery would be the best but so far I havent been able to figure that part out...
Now the refresh nor the mouseover works... Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your handlers are a little confused, based on your description of the functionality, I would expect the refreshInterval to be set immediately, not on a mouseout, and I would use the mouseover as described on the jquery API:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var refreshInterval;

        $(document).ready(function() {
            refreshInterval = setInterval(function() {
                $("#latestChats").load('somedynamicpage.html');
            }, 1500);

            $("#latestChats").mouseover(function() {
                clearInterval(refreshInterval);
            });
        });        
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QG354/ (with an alert to show the mouseover being triggered)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the div refresh now works perfectly but the mouseover has no effect, it keeps refreshing :( Your code:     var refreshInterval;
    $(function() {refreshInterval = setInterval(function() {$("#latestChats").load('chats_algemeen.php');}, 5000);});
    $("#latestChats").mouseover(function() {clearInterval(refreshInterval);});

Comment: Hmm, if you put `alert('triggered');` before the `clearInterval(refreshInterval);` line, does the alert get fired?

Comment: It looks like it doesnt even execute that line. No alert triggered. I could try to remove the refr.interval and only test that mouseover

Comment: That alert alone breaks my code, tinymce is not loaded with the mouseover alone. When left intact is does load (inc. that refresh)

Comment: I've edited the code in my answer - if the handler isn't being fired I think it is trying to set the handler before element has loaded, so I put it in the `$()`

Comment: Sadly, no changes to the mouseover. Cant there be another part of the code that breaks it before it even executes? the last line >> ); << has no start could that be the problem?

Comment: Edited again to sort out the silly brackets issue I introduced :)

Comment: Now the refresh function stopped working :( ive tried to put it in a simple HTML file where it just requests another .html file same result, no refresh.

Comment: I'm running a bit of a blank now as to why this has stopped working with just the code snippet to go on. Is there any chance you could knock up a jsfiddle which roughly reproduces your situation and I could try and figure it out for you.

Comment: That worked! youre awesome! Ill study this code so I can expand its uses. thank you so much!